# How can I make flex items shrink until wrapping is necessary, and then expand to fill the new space?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox parent component with width about 1200px, and several child items with min-width about 400px. Nominally, with a screen width above 1200, and taking into consideration margins and borders, I can fit two child items per row, each about 600px wide.

With a decreasing screen width from about 1200px to about 800px, the two child items gradually shrink down to about 400px. When the screen size goes below about 800px, wrapping occurs, meaning I now have one child item per row.

What I would like is for those child items to expand back to about 800px to fill their rows. What I get is child items that remain at about 400px wide.

If I set grow: 1 on the child items, they start off at one per row, each using the full 1200px.

I'm hoping that there is some combination of min-width, flex-basis, max-width, and grow (and maybe something else) that can achieve my desired result.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet that I believe achieves what you want:

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1200px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .box {
    outline: solid red 1px;
    min-width: 400px;
    flex-grow: 2;
    /* flex: 2 0 50%; */ /* If you want to ensure that you never get more than 2 items per row */
  }
</style>
```

In sum, the property you want is `flex-grow`: it ensures that the component will fill up available space on its row up to the specified factor (in this case 2, to go from 400px width up to 800px).

If it's important not to fit more than two elements on a row on wider screens, I added an alternative `flex` property for that which uses a `flex-basis` of 50% to make the components "greedier" in flowing onto a row than they would be otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your snippet. I think I need to do more work to understand the "flex-grow" attribute. In particular, my understanding was that the flex-grow value on one item was relative to the other items. Thus if all the child items have "flex-grow: 2", they would all grow the same amount. The same argument would seem to apply for flex-grow values of 1 or 3 or anything else.

Comment: One additional issue: with an odd number of child items, can I make the one in the last row be the same width (half the screen width) as the ones in the earlier rows?

Comment: I think the short answer is that with out-of-the-box flex styling you can't. I'd love to be able to explain why in terms of the design intentions of flexbox, but honestly it's a bit of an alien creature to me and I just don't know why it allows certain things but not others.
One option here is to use media queries to figure out when to fix the size of the flex-flowed elements; another hacky way would be to add a dummy element at the end with height of 0 and width the same as the others, so it takes up half the area when the count is odd and a full row (with no height) when the count is even.